# Why this dynamic programming recurrence relation is correct?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Consider you have a screen. Now we can do two operations on  the screen:

1. Copy content on the screen
2. Paste copied content on the screen

Suppose at the beginning, the clipboard is empty and there is one character on the screen. If we have N operations, how we can print the maximum number of characters on the screen using N operations of copy and pastes?

The answer is
`DP[N]=max(2DP[N-2],3DP[N-3])`

But how do we get the above result? And why below formulations aren't correct?

1. `DP[N]=max(DP[N-1],2DP[N-2])`
2. `DP[N]=2DP[N-2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Explaining the correct recurrence

Having the `Nth` operation as print, the `N-1`th operation could be either copy or paste.

1. `N-1`th copy, `N`th paste.
   Copying at `N-1` would mean copying `dp[N-2]` characters, so the total here becomes `2*dp[N-2]`
2. `N-2`th copy,`N-1`th paste, `N`th paste.
   Copying at `N-2` would mean copying `dp[N-3]` characters, so the total here becomes `3*dp[N-3]` (original `dp[N-3]` + pasted twice).
3. `N-3`th copy at 3 pastes wouldn't make sense, since you could get the same result via step 1 twice.

So the result becomes `dp[N] = max(2*dp[N-2],3*dp[N-3])`.

##### Issue with your recurrence

1. `DP[N]=max(DP[N-1],2DP[N-2])` wouldn't work because there's no way to track if you have the `N`th operation as a copy or paste.
2. `DP[N]=2DP[N-2]` misses the case of two consecutive pastes (hint: First few values in the `dp` table are listed, figure out the case for `dp[5]`:

```
i -> dp[i]
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      2
4      4
5      6
```

Comment: @user355834 Assuming `x` characters at the first copy, `CPPP` will give `4x` chars, and `CPCP` will also have the same result